# how to recursively call a generic method analyzing properties

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm creating a method that will analyze an instance of a class that I have created, checking each of the properties on that class for `string` types and then checking if those `string` properties are `null` or empty.

Code:

```
public class RootClass
{
    public string RootString1 { get; set; }
    public string RootString2 { get; set; }
    public int RootInt1 { get; set; }

    public Level1ChildClass1 RootLevel1ChildClass11 { get; set; }
    public Level1ChildClass1 RootLevel1ChildClass12 { get; set; }
    public Level1ChildClass2 RootLevel1ChildClass21 { get; set; }
}

public class Level1ChildClass1
{
    public string Level1String1 { get; set; }
    public string Level1String2 { get; set; }
    public int Level1Int1 { get; set; }
}

public class Level1ChildClass2
{
    public string Level1String1 { get; set; }
    public string Level1String2 { get; set; }
    public int Level1Int1 { get; set; }

    public Level2ChildClass1 Level1Level2ChildClass11 { get; set; }
    public Level2ChildClass1 Level1Level2ChildClass12 { get; set; }
    public Level2ChildClass2 Level1Level2ChildClass22 { get; set; }
}

public class Level2ChildClass1
{
    public string Level2String1 { get; set; }
    public string Level2String2 { get; set; }
    public int Level2Int1 { get; set; }
}

public class Level2ChildClass2
{
    public string Level2String1 { get; set; }
    public string Level2String2 { get; set; }
    public int Level2Int1 { get; set; }
}
```

Not all the properties on the class are strings, some of them are instances of other classes, which have their own properties, which also need to be analyzed the same way. Basically, the method will return `true` if any of the properties are strings with a value on the RootClass or anywhere on sub-levels of the class (for example, if `RootLevel1ChildClass11` has a string property with a value).

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static bool ObjectHasStringData<T>(this T obj)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
        if (propertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(property.GetValue(obj, null) as string))
                    return true;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException) { } // we want to ignore NullReferenceExceptions
        }
        else if (!propertyType.IsValueType)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ObjectHasStringData(property.GetValue(obj, null)))
                    return true;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException) { } // we want to ignore NullReferenceExceptions
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

this works great on the first layer (so any `string` within the `RootClass`), but once I start using it recursively on the `if (ObjectHasStringData(property.GetValue(obj, null)))` line, the return value of `property.GetValue()` is `object`, so when calling the method recursively, `T` is `object`.

I can get the `Type` of the current object, but how do I convert the `object` returned from `property.GetValue()` to the actual type of the property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest not making that a generic method, just have it accept any object, and use `GetType` to get the type (unless it's null). The generics doesn't really seem to add anything of value here.

So, remove the type parameter, use `obj.GetType()`, and don't recurse if the object is null!

Also, `(propertyType)obj)` won't work, and if it would it would have no use. Casting is only for type safety and determining (at compile time) how to interact with an object. To System.Reflection it doesn't make any difference.

```
public static bool ObjectHasStringData( this object obj )
{
    if( obj == null )
        return false;
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var property in properties)
     ...
}
```

Comment: i guess i thought that using `object.GetType()` would return `object`, not the type of the actual object... it seems to be working though, so I'm going to test a little more and then mark as answer

Comment: The type of an object doesn't change with casting - it only changes how you interact with it. So `GetType` will always return the underlying type, regardless of how you are referencing it.